# Express request throwing 401 unauthorized

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, mern

Backend route for creating a list is showing error. Throwing 401(unauthorised) even after logging in and auth-token being present.

**list.js(route)**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');
const member = require('../middleware/member');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const User = require('../models/User');
const Board = require('../models/Board');
const List = require('../models/List');

router.post(
  '/',
  [auth, member, [check('title', 'Title is required').not().isEmpty()]],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    try {
      const title = req.body.title;
      const boardId = req.header('boardId');

      const newList = new List({ title });
      const list = await newList.save();

      const board = await Board.findById(boardId);
      board.lists.push(list.id);

      const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
      board.activity.unshift({
        text: `${user.name} added '${title}' to this board`,
      });
      await board.save();

      res.json(list);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  }
);

router.get('/boardLists/:boardId', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const board = await Board.findById(req.params.boardId);
    if (!board) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Board not found' });
    }

    const lists = [];
    for (const listId of board.lists) {
      lists.push(await List.findById(listId));
    }

    res.json(lists);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});

router.get('/:id', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const list = await List.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!list) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'List not found' });
    }

    res.json(list);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});

router.patch(
  '/rename/:id',
  [auth, member, [check('title', 'Title is required').not().isEmpty()]],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    try {
      const list = await List.findById(req.params.id);
      if (!list) {
        return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'List not found' });
      }

      list.title = req.body.title;
      await list.save();

      res.json(list);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  }
);

router.patch('/archive/:archive/:id', [auth, member], async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const list = await List.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!list) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'List not found' });
    }

    list.archived = req.params.archive === 'true';
    await list.save();

    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
    const board = await Board.findById(req.header('boardId'));
    board.activity.unshift({
      text: list.archived
        ? `${user.name} archived list '${list.title}'`
        : `${user.name} sent list '${list.title}' to the board`,
    });
    await board.save();

    res.json(list);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});

router.patch('/move/:id', [auth, member], async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const toIndex = req.body.toIndex ? req.body.toIndex : 0;
    const boardId = req.header('boardId');
    const board = await Board.findById(boardId);
    const listId = req.params.id;
    if (!listId) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'List not found' });
    }

    board.lists.splice(board.lists.indexOf(listId), 1);
    board.lists.splice(toIndex, 0, listId);
    await board.save();

    res.send(board.lists);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**auth.js(middleware)**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
require('dotenv').config();

const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.header('x-auth-token');

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'No token, authorization denied' });
  }

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Token is not valid' });
  }
};

module.exports = auth;
```

Error while I am running the whole project

[image: Picture showing error]

> Error - 401 unauthorized

> Response - You must be a member of this board to make changes
> **(I am sending the request as an admin/member of the board)**

**member.js(middleware)**

```
const Board = require('../models/Board');

const member = async (req, res, next) => {
  const board = await Board.findById(req.header('boardId'));
  if (!board) {
    return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Board not found' });
  }

  const members = board.members.map((member) => member.user);
  if (members.includes(req.user.id)) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({ msg: 'You must be a member of this board to make changes' });
  }
};

module.exports = member;
```

Ps - I am using proxy in client package.json

> **Github Repo**
> https://github.com/JavaKaran/trello-demo

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question and lookup your code in your repo : https://github.com/JavaKaran/trello-demo

I think this is happened because u didn't send the "x-auth-token" from your client to server

You have to set the headers from your client request e.g : in your client/src/actions/board.js

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-auth-token': {{your_token}}
  },
};


export const addList = (formData) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const body = JSON.stringify(formData);

    const res = await axios.post('/api/lists', body, config);

    dispatch({
      type: ADD_LIST,
      payload: res.data,
    });

    dispatch(getActivity());
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: BOARD_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
    });
  }
};
```

Hope this answer could help you to solve the problem.

Comment: x-auth-token has been set as the header for every axios request in utils/setAuthToken. Error has been updated and should be now more clear